# How do I increase the number of columns displayed in Jupyter with R?

Tags: r, jupyter

I am using a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel. When I print rectangular data, e.g., a matrix, it only shows me the first 10 and last 10 columns:

[image]

The same thing happens for data.frames, or any other object that is printed in an HTML table.

How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Figured it out. You can set these in options():

```
options(repr.matrix.max.cols=50, repr.matrix.max.rows=100)
```

They default to cols=20 and rows=60.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It solved the problem. Maybe I should have posted a screenshot showing the problem resolved?

Comment: This is a good answer. Does anyone know how to change Jupyter's default so we don't have to include this in every script?

Comment: @carbocation Maybe try putting them in a startup script? If you need tips on how to do that, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818538/where-can-i-put-a-startup-script-in-jupyter. Note, I haven't tried this myself, just a suggestion.

Comment: @Ma Li that error looks like Python but this is a question about R.

Answer (score -3):

Jupiter truncates the output. But if you do

```
print(matrix(1:30, ncol=30))
```

or

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:30, ncol=30))
print(df)
```

you should get the full matrix or df output.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I wanted to know how to change the Jupyter HTML display, as shown in the included screenshot, and these answers produce a text display.

Comment: @Jonathan sorry, if this was not what you were looking for, but you have found your own answer to it anyhow.