# Where can I put a startup script in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, startup

I'm looking for a way to put my startup script in Jupyter. In IPython, I put it under the `$IPYTHON_DIR/profile_default/startup/`.

In Jupyter, it seems that the config file should be `$JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. However, I would like to use my startup file, which import a slew of Python libraries at the launch of the kernel.

Where can I put such file in Jupyter?

Answer (score 36):

You can get the default startup script folder via this in jupyter notebook:

```
get_ipython().profile_dir.startup_dir
```

On my Windows PC, the folder is: `C:\Users\myusername\.ipython\profile_default\startup`

And do read the README file under the folder.

```
    Files will be run in lexicographical order, so you can control
the execution order of files with a prefix, e.g.::

    00-first.py
    50-middle.py
    99-last.ipy
```

So you can put a file named `00-xx.py` under the folder.

Comment: Is there any way to make this local to the "project" folder, or something of the like?

Comment: @tutuca https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html#envvar-IPYTHONDIR is what you're looking for - setting it to `.`.

Comment: Missed that reading the docs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way to have project-local startup files while also using the user's IPython config and startup files?