# How to run Python code before every jupyter notebook kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have a code snippet that I'd like to run every time I open a jupyter notebook (in my case it's opening up a Spark connection). Let's say I save that code in a .py script:

-- startup.py --

```py
sc = "This is a spark connection"
```

I want to be able to have that code snippet run every time I open a kernel. I've found some stuff about the [Jupyter Configuration File](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#id9), but it doesn't seem like variables defined there show up when I try to run

```py
print(sc)
```

in a notebook. Is there a command-line option that I could use -- something like:

```
jupyter notebook --startup-script startup.py
```

or do I have to include something like

```py
from startup import sc, sqlContext
```

in all of the notebooks where I want those variables to be defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start ipython running a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323230/start-ipython-running-a-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to create a startup file as you suggested, and include it via

```
%load ~/.jupyter/startup.py
```

This will paste the content of the file into the cell, which you can then execute.

Alternatively, you can write a minimal, installable package that contains all your startup code.

**Pro:** Doesn't clutter your notebook

**Con:** More difficult to make small changes.

Answer (score 1):

A custom package or explicit loading is not needed (though might be preferred if you work with others): you *can* have auto-executed startup scripts
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051758/2611913